# Canvas Circle Tear in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a line coming out of a circle in Javascript.
Look at the square I want it to look like that.

For some reason, the circle is following the path of the line instead of being a different element altogether. I am incredibly confused. Is there supposed to be some stopping condition I'm supposed to implement for the line?

[image]

This is the code being used to draw this:

```
if (this.sex == "Male") {
      // Relation Line
      // TODO: Setup so this shows only if it has a
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo((this.x + (this.x / 4)), (this.y + (this.y / 4)))
      c.lineTo((this.x + (this.x / 4)), (this.y + (this.y / 4)) + 60)
      c.stroke()
      // END Relation Line
      // Shape
      c.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50)
      c.fillStyle = 'blue'
    }
    else {
      // Relation Line
      // TODO: Setup so this shows only if it has a
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(this.x, this.y + 30)
      c.lineTo(this.x, this.y + 60)
      c.stroke()
      // END Relation Line
      // Shape
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
      c.fillStyle = 'pink'
    }
    c.fill()
```

This is stored inside of a draw function which is called inside of an animate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling the shape will connect end of path with its beginning.
Just begin new shape with `beginPath`

```js
function a(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      var c = document.getElementById('shape').getContext('2d');

// Relation Line
      // TODO: Setup so this shows only if it has a
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(this.x, this.y + 30)
      c.lineTo(this.x, this.y + 60)
      c.stroke()
      // END Relation Line
      // Shape
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
      c.fillStyle = 'pink'
      c.fill()
    
}

function b(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      var c = document.getElementById('shape').getContext('2d');

      // Relation Line
      // TODO: Setup so this shows only if it has a
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(this.x, this.y + 30)
      c.lineTo(this.x, this.y + 60)
      c.stroke()
      // END Relation Line
      // Shape
      c.beginPath()
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
      c.fillStyle = 'pink'
      c.fill()        
}

new a(50, 50);
new b(150, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="shape"></canvas>
```